# ROS Python main loop hanging for few seconds

Tags: python, freeze, ros, ubuntu-20.04

I have a problem in ROS 1 Noetic and Python in Ubuntu 20 on Raspberry Pi. I am running a few other nodes and the main node. In the main node it often happens that the code randomly hangs. This happens in a callback which receives information from another node. But it also happens if I only run the main loop. For simplicity purpose, I am attaching image of how that happens in the main loop. The first image shows the code and the second image shows the output.

[image]

[image]

As seen from the second picture, the main loop randomly hanged for whole 2.5 seconds.

If you need some more information, I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your full code. It seems most likely that the callback takes up time. You also have no sleep in your main loop.

Comment: @BTables I have disabled the callback for this demonstration. I can't post full code, because it is huge - it has many nodes.. And also, it is company's code so I can't share it. But, I will try to do a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem. It wasn't with the code, but with the SD card. When I switched to another SD card, the problem was gone.

This is the SD card which had the problem:
[https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-Digital-32GB-microSDHC-SDCA3/dp/B00RVNGGT8?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RVNGGT8)

And this is the one which didn't:
[https://www.amazon.com/Sandisk-Ultra-Micro-UHS-I-Adapter/dp/B073K14CVB?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073K14CVB)

The one which didn't have the problem has significantly greater read speed. I guess this is the difference that caused the problem. Or maybe the card I used before was faulty in some other way.

What do you think? Could the read speed have such an impact?